# Link the Application data and AspUserRole

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

In Role Table, we have list of roles

```
RoleId | RoleName
------------------
  1    | Admin
  2    | OrgAdmin
  3    | ProjectAdmin
  4    | TeamLeader
  5    | TeamMember
```

**Concept:**

- Once the user signup for an organization we assigned the OrgAdmin
  role.
- OrgAdmin invites ProjectAdmins to manage the project.
- ProjectAdmin invites Team Leader and Team Member to join in their
  projects.
- Team Member can handle multiple projects, in other words he/she can be PA in
  other project which is managing by other organization.

> **For Example:**
>
> John invites to be a Team Member from Organization1--> Project1.
>   Same user can also be invites to manage the other project from
>   Organization2--> Project1. So John have two role ProjectAdmin(PA) and
>   TeamMember(TM), but PA is for Project2 and TM is for Project1

In AspUserRole table, we can maintain the UserId and RoleId but user have multiple role(PA/TM) from different organization, how to maintain this in AspUserRole table or do I need to user different table to maintain these relationship?

I tried to maintain the separate table as below. Do I missing some in built functionality of Roles?

```
UserId | RoleId | OrgId 
------------------------
  1    |  1     |  NULL 
  2    |  2     |   1    
  3    |  3     |   1   
  4    |  4     |   1
  4    |  3     |   2
```

**Technology:**

- Asp.Net 4.5, C#
- MVC 5
- Entity Framework code first
- SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one table, but if an Organization can have more than one Project, then you will need to add ProjectId as well.

Comment: I agree with you. Do we need to maintain the separate table or in aspuserrole table is fine

Comment: In the same table is fine.